# sqlite3 - while loop is not executed

Tags: xcode4, sqlite

Strange Problem anyone please solve it

While loop is not executing, in my read database code.

Here is my code

```
NSString * query=@"select usernote from savenote where recipename like ? ";

            const char * sqlStatement=[query UTF8String];

            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2 (database, sqlStatement,-1,&compiledStatement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
               sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[selString UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
                NSLog(@"selected:%@",selString);


                while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)== SQLITE_ROW)
                {


                    NSString * notz=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];
                    [Notes addObject:notz];

                    NSLog(@"n:%@",Notes);
                    txt.text=[Notes objectAtIndex:0];

                }

            }
        }
```

In the above code all works fine except the while loop is never being executed.

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to step through your code? Perhaps the *if* statement in which the *while* loop is contained never evaluates to true. If not, maybe your call to *sqlite3_prepare_v2()* is failing...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the query. Add *single-quotes*(`'`) in the `like` clause.

```
"select usernote from savenote where recipename like '?'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this link](http://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/using-like-statement-in-sqlite-3-from.html)

In your case Code will look like,

```
const char * sqlStatement = "select usernote from savenote where recipename like ?001 ";

sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[selString UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```